# How to merge these 2 MySQL Select queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to merge 2 MySQL queries into 2 because of some performance increasement. Basically I'd like the query to search for an element in 2 tables. If it doesn't find in one, it should search in the other one. This is the reason I have created 2 queries, but I'm sure it will be slower in the log run than 1 query.

I have the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT a_id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'George'
SELECT b_id FROM table2 WHERE name = 'George'
```

How is it possible to create one query of these? It should only return 1 id where it found the match.

Comment: Have you tried a UNION in combination with LIMIT 1 ? But when an ID is returned, you no longer know what table it came from.

Comment: The returned id doesn't matter, I just need to know if there is a result or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UNION ALL query:

```
SELECT a_id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'George'
UNION ALL
SELECT b_id FROM table2
WHERE
  name = 'George'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT a_id FROM table1 WHERE name = 'George')
```

or this:

```
SELECT a_id, 1 as t FROM table1 WHERE name = 'George'
UNION ALL
SELECT b_id, 2 as t FROM table2 WHERE name = 'George'
ORDER BY t
LIMIT 1
```

but I don't think it will be faster than running two separated queries.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT COALESCE(a_id,
       (SELECT b_id FROM table2 WHERE name = 'George'))
FROM table1 WHERE name = 'George'
```